# Using pandoc-crossref with R bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown

Is it possible to use pandoc-crossref in bookdown?

I tried to change the yaml header to:

```
output: 
    bookdown::tufte_book2:
        toc: yes
        highlight: tango
        pandoc_args: -F /usr/local/bin/pandoc-crossref
```

Which should pass the filter to pandoc, but I get the error:

```
pandoc: Error running filter  pandoc-crossref:
Could not find executable ' pandoc-crossref'.
```

The above error does not make sense, as I entered the correct path. What kind of env is bookdown using, which is precluding the access to the filter file?

Comment: The `bookdown` output formats already include cross-referencing. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: How to reference a figure and how to reference a section?

Comment: @KevinArseneau it would be useful to get an answer to this question for equation numbering in Word output. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example

````
---
output: bookdown::html_document2
---

# Section name {#id}

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.cap='test plot'}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot. To cross-reference the figure, use `\@ref(fig:pressure)` to produce Figure \@ref(fig:pressure). All this is found within the section \@ref(id).
````

Which produces...

[image]

See https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/figures.html for the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue while I was trying to put numbers to equations in Word files ([SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47985267/2275286)). I got the same error `Could not find executable 'pandoc-crossref'`.

My RStudio installation (on Windows) did not come with `pandoc-crossref`. Here is what I did:

1. Downloaded `pandoc-crossref` from [here](https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref/releases).
2. Find the path where RStudio saved the file `pandoc.exe`:

```
rmarkdown::find_pandoc()
```

3. Put the `pandoc-crossref.exe` in the folder I got in (2).