# Equation numbering in Rmarkdown, output to word

Tags: r-markdown

I am trying to knit a .Rmd file to a word file, where I need to include equations and their numbers.

The code I tried looks like below:

```
$$
\begin{cases}
\tag{1}
\frac{dX}{dt}=a\\\frac{dY}{dt}=b
\end{cases}
$$
```

But this doesn't work.

There is a similar question

[Equation Numbering in Rmarkdown - For Export to Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47985267/equation-numbering-in-rmarkdown-for-export-to-word)

Yet the answer doesn't work for me. I am wondering if anyone have a good solution to this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, @user15578296.

Here is your equation ready for Word:

```
---
output: word_document
---

$$\begin{cases} \frac{dX}{dt}=a\\\frac{dY}{dt}=b \end{cases}$$
```

Regarding the numbering, you should follow the answer provided in your mentioned linked question.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But that solution doesn't work for me. After downloading "pandoc-crossref" from the site, and when I knit the file, I was prompted "'panic-corssref' cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified. BTW, I am a mac user.